# Airdrop with ERC20 Token

Tags: erc-20, gas-limit, airdrop

What I’m trying to determine is if we create a new ERC20 token and group to distribute 10,000 wallet addresses as part of an airdrop campaign when the token is launched, can we avoid paying gas for each transaction or at the least minimize our transaction cost?

Also, will it make any difference if I call this method from constructor and when I call it by accessing that method through myEtherWallet?

Comment: Hi @smarx, I have gone through that discussion. But my question is little bit different as i want to know if i can distribute the tokens at the time of creation of my ERC20 token as a airdrop to reduce a transaction fees. I'm not sure if it's a different concept or same as asked by someone in the mentioned discussion by you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Assigning balances directly in the token constructor is cheaper, but I do not think you can do it for 10K addresses. Don't be cheap if you want to make an air drop, just pay for it.

Comment: You should implement a function on the airdrop for bulk transfers that takes arrays of addresses and an array of amounts to send (or an amount to send per eth, or just a flat amount to each address). It's not free, but it's much cheaper than individual transactions. I don't really agree with the "just pay for it" ideology because if everyone is more conscious about gas usage, then it should be cheaper for everyone. Don't fill up blocks with gas if you can avoid it.